# How to store and then display picture using vb6 and oracle?

Tags: oracle, vb6

```
'code to load picture into database table
Private Function GetPic()
  Dim filelen As Long
  Dim numlock As Integer
  Dim leftover As Long
  Const blocksize = 100000
  Dim pic As String
  Dim bytedata() As Byte
  Dim sfile As Integer

  sql = "select PICS from student_record_database " //empty field with no pictures
  RES.Open sql, CON, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
  sfile = App.Path & "/mypic/Book1.xls" //error : type mismatch

  Open sfile For Binary Access Read As #1
  filelen = LOF(sfile)
  If filelen = 0 Then
    Close sfile
    MsgBox ("empty or not found")
  Else

    numlock = filelen / blocksize
    leftover = filelen Mod blocksize
    ReDim bytedata(leftover)
    Get sfile, , bytedata()
    RES(1).AppendChunk bytedata()
    ReDim bytedata(blocksize)

    For i = 1 To numlock
      Get sfile, , bytedata()
      RES(1).AppendChunk bytedata()
    Next i

    RES.Update
    Close sfile
  End If
End Function

'code to display picture in picture box from table
Private Function ShowPic()
  Dim bytedata() As Byte
  Dim file As String
  Dim filelen As Long
  Dim numlock As Integer
  Dim leftover As Long
  Const blocksize = 100000

  file = App.Path & "\image1.jpeg"
  Open file For Binary As #1
  numlock = filelen / blocksize
  leftover = filelen Mod blocksize
  bytedata() = RES(1).GetChunk(leftover)
  Put file, , bytedata()

  For i = 1 To numlock
    bytedata() = RES(1).GetChunk(blocksize)
    Put file, , bytedata()
  Next i
  Close file
End Function
```

Here is my full code to insert pictures using vb in an oracle table database.
Next I display those pictures in picture box of vb application as per their records, but it is showing an error of "type mismatch" and picture is not shown in picture box.

Comment: What does "showing errors" mean? Please _always_ post the full error message so people don't have to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declared sFile as an integer, but are trying to load a string in it

```
Dim sFile as string
sfile = App.Path & "/mypic/Book1.xls"
```

Comment: if I did so then it shows type mismatch for  <code> filelen = LOF(sfile) </code>

Comment: LOF() expects a filenumber so that should be : filelen = LOF(1) .... btw it is better to use FreeFile to get a unique filenumber : intFile = FreeFile .. and then use intFile instead of 1

Comment: is it necessary to give <picture1.picture=loadpicture(path)> in the code??

Comment: yes, if "path" contains the location of a picture file, and you want to show that picture in "picture1" then you have to that with that line of code

Comment: Then why we are using this whole code???? load picture() normally loads the picture in picture box..........